# Tax classes on WooCommerce with Dokan

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tax, dokan

I have a marketplace with Dokan Pro installed.

I would like that when vendors create a product ,there is no tax.

But, I need 20% VAT on the products I sell as an administrator. I mean for example that vendors can buy different products to promote their stores. So I need 20% VAT on these products but no taxes on all the others products create by the vendors.

I hope I was clear ?

if someone can help me, I will appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your requirements are as simple as described, you can just use other tax class(es) for your products than your vendors use.

However, in most business cases it is not as simple as that, starting with invoice requirements and reaching up to scenarios where you and your vendors need to collect taxes.

Then you need a solution that also

1. handles the invoicing stuff (VAT numbers on vendors end, etc..)
2. dynamically calculates and collect taxes based on many factors, like the customer and the vendor location, the products they are selling, businesses customers or private consumers and many more.

You may check out [Global Tax for Dokan](https://www.blueantoinette.com/product/global-tax-for-dokan/) and [Global Tax for Dokan Invoice](https://www.blueantoinette.com/product/global-tax-for-dokan-invoice/) for these use cases. Alternatively and more generally you can also check out [Global Tax for Marketplaces and More (GT4M)](https://gt4m.com/).